# SSH connection to github repo messing up ssh tunnel to remote server

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm currently working with data from a remote database, which I access with pgAdmin 4 via a SSH tunnel. The server port is 5432 and the SSH tunnel port is 22.

Today I decided to put my code on github and connect to my repo through SSH. As it was the first time, I generated and set up a SSH key as mentioned in GitHub's [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent). I pushed my code, everything's fine, but then I had to get some data from my DB, and from there on, I was unable to connect to the DB server anymore.

I thought maybe it was because they were sharing port 22 ? So I tried changing my repo url "git@github.com:myName/myRepo" to "ssh://git@github.com:2000/myName/myRepo", but still I couldn't access the remote server. I tried killing the ssh-agent, useless as well.

To make sure it was indeed github ssh connection messing up things, I restarted my computer and connected to the DB first thing after the restart and it worked. Then I opened VS Code (which I suppose automatically connected to the distant repo) and then I tried to reconnect to the distant server and I wasn't able anymore.

I'm on windows 10, let me know if you need other information but any help would be appreciated!

Also since it's also about github I'm not sure whether this fits SE or if I should post to superuser.com instead.

Thank you.

Comment: You haven't accidentally uploaded your DB access credentials to a public GitHub repo, have you?

Comment: @srn nah credentials are not stored in any part that I upload + repo is private anyway

Comment: How did you set up the SSH tunnel?

Comment: @JimRedmond actually that is a good point, I guess the first I should have done is ask the actual people who set up the ssh tunnel how they did it... I will ask and let you know if it improves anything